# vim script leaves characters in stdin

Tags: bash, vim, vi, prompt

I'm trying to use vim with -s option to run a script that replaces some lines in a file like this (text.txt):

```
test1
ab
ac
ae
test2
sd
```

Script file is like this (script):

```
:silent %s/test1\zs\_.\+\zetest2/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\n\(\w\)', '\n#\1', 'g')/g
:wq
```

It comments out lines between test1 and test2. Which is what I want. What I don't want though is output before and after prompt. I run it and get:

```
user@hostname: ~/vimtest$ vim -s script text.txt 
^[[?1;2cuser@hostname: ~/vimtest$ 1;2c
```

So this `^[[?1;2c` is bad news already but `1;2c` is in the input as if I already typed it. If I hit enter it gives me a bash error. So I have to remove these symbols each time the script is used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `vim` (or some vim startup script) is trying to figure out what type of terminal you are using. The `^[[?1;2c`, with the last few characters left in the input buffer, is almost certainly part of your terminal emulator's response to a DA (Device Attributes) query. You can see this yourself by typing in bash:

```
printf '\033[c'
```

or, to see the complete return, pause a bit:

```
printf '\033[c'; sleep 0.1; echo
```

The response `\033[?1;2c` means "I'm a VT100 with Advanced Video Option.", which is what `xterm` and many other console programs respond. (The Linux console itself responds `\033[?6c`, which means "I'm a VT102.")

The reason that only `1;2c` is left in the console input buffer, by the way, is that the initial escape code `\033[?` was ignored when it was read. The `readline` library will ignore it without echoing it, whereas normal console input will echo it and then ignore it; that's why the two shell commands above differ.

I can't reproduce this problem with my `vim` installation, so I don't really even know where to start looking. But you might try to see if disabling all startup files helps:

```
vim -u NONE -s script text.txt
```

If that helps, start disabling installed extensions one by one until you find the one which is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Option `-u NONE` worked out and the culprit was `syntax on` line in `~/.vimrc`

Comment: @lonelyelk: so somewhere in your syntax files (presumably in the initialization), there is some vim script with a bug. If you want to start digging, look at the files in your `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax` directory, starting with `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim` and `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/synload.vim`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/test1\zs\_.\+\ze\ntest2/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\n', '\n#', 'g')/g
:wq
```

this is tested here, it changed the input file in required way.

Some changes done based on your command:

- add `\n` after `\ze`
- in substitute() function we can just handle the `\n`, we don't need to capture the word after the `\n`

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you tagged the question with `bash`, so I thought a shell-solution should be accepted too.

```
awk '/test1/{p=1;print;next}/test2/{p=0;print;next}{$0=(p?"#":"")$0}7' file
```

this awk oneliner should do that for you. vim is very powerful editor, I love vim. But if you want to do some automatic transformation, I prefer a script or a proper text processing tool. On a linux box you can always find one. It is easier to test and debug.

Test with your input:

```
kent$  cat f
test1
ab
ac
ae
test2
sd

kent$  awk '/test1/{p=1;print;next}/test2/{p=0;print;next}{$0=(p?"#":"")$0}7' f
test1
#ab
#ac
#ae
test2
sd
```

If you want to save the text back to your file, you can :

```
awk '...' file > tmp.file && mv tmp.file file
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposition. It is less convenient to sudo though. All this came from a necessity to comment out and then turn back on chunks of /etc/hosts file. Like daily.